# Cognos BI 10.1.2 how to create a new user?

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-10

I'm trying to create a new user in Cognos BI 10.1.2.

After a bit of research I've discovered that a new user must actually be created in an "authentication source" such as for example: IBM Cognos Series 7 namespace, Active Directory Server, Custom Authentication Provider, LDAP, CA SiteMinder, RACF, SAP.

So my question is, how do I setup this "authentication source" and then get the users that I create in that authentication source to shown up in the Cognos Connection web portal?

Comment: Have you read the documentation at all?

Comment: @Andrew To be fair, it's IBM documentation. It's some of the densest, least informative doc imaginable.  IBM doc is proof that technically correct is *not* the best kind of correct.  To OP: In Cognos 8.4, at least, you had to run the IBM Cognos Configuration program from the server to configure new authentication methods.  The user guide for that should also be on the server.  Then you can access IBM Cognos Administration from the Cognos website, and you should see the new authentication resource listed there.